# JS: check existence of a full object using a key?

Tags: javascript

I am iterating through data and doing want to assign a random number to a `fontObj` only if it is unique

a `fontObj` looks like:

```
{
   postscript: "Calibri",
   style: "Bold",
   family: "Calibri"
}
```

I want to iterate through paragraphs in my code and use the `fontObj` as a key.

pseudocode:

```
if (fontMap[fontObj]) {
   console.log("Already found: " + fontObj + " and the random number is " + fontMap[fontObj])
} else {
   fontMap[fontObj] = Math.random()
}
```

what is the best way to structure that since I can't check the existence of an entire object using a key?

Comment: Object keys are strings, you can't use an object as the key. You'll need to convert it to a unique string first.

Comment: thanks.  What about using `maps` ?  Aren't they more flexible about what is used as a key?  I'd rather avoid stringifying my objects to use as keys.

Comment: Maps require you to use the same *reference* if you plan on using objects as keys. Maps do no not use deep-equals to test if the key matches an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an object as a key, you have to use a string.

If the objects all have the same properties, simply make a string out of those values.

```
function fontObjToKey(fontObj) {
    return `${fontObj.postscript}/${fontObj.style}/${fontObj.family}`;
}

let fontKey = fontObjToKey(fontObj);
if (fontMap[fontKey]) {
    console.log("Already found: " + fontKey + " and the random number is " + fontMap[fontKey]);
} else {
    fontMap[fontKey] = Math.random();
}
```